# how to set particular date in jquery mobile datebox control, highlight it in datepicker

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am creating one application with  jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1 release. I have a page which is having input form to get details. It has date field , so for that I used jquery.mobile.datebox . See http://dev.jtsage.com/ for its demo. 
I am facing one issue with it, when I set particular date value for date field on page-load , the value is shown in textbox. But when user click on date-picker icon- the calendar still highlight today's date and show current month only.

If anybody has used the same control then please help about , how to achieve like  if there is any date value the text box then when you launch the datepicker, it should start from that date.
For eg. here I am setting date of March month, then ,when user clicks on datepicker , march month calendar should be shown.

Here is my code file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <title>Detailed information</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.css" />
        <link type="text/css" href="jquery.mobile.datebox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).bind( "mobileinit", function(){
            $.mobile.page.prototype.options.degradeInputs.date = 'text';            

        }); 
        </script>       
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile.datebox.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
            //Setting start date value on pageload 
            $('#startdate').val('2011-03-20');
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="home">
            <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
                <a href="daily_schedule.html" rel="external" data-icon="arrow-l">back</a>
                <h1>Detailed Information</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <form action="" method="get" onsubmit="validate();" id="frmdetailedinfo">
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <input readonly="true"  name="startdate" type="date" data-role="datebox" id="startdate" data-options='{"mode": "calbox", "useDialogForceFalse": true, "noAnimation": true}'/>
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                            <div class="ui-block-a">
                                <button type="submit" data-theme="a" name="submit" data-icon="check" value="submit-value">
                                    Save
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <!--content-->
        </div>
        <!--page-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set it in the tag itself:

```
<input readonly="true"  
       name="startdate" 
       type="date" 
       data-role="datebox" 
       id="startdate" 
       data-options='{
           "mode": "calbox", 
           "useDialogForceFalse": true, 
           "noAnimation": true
        }'/>
```

Becomes this

```
    <input readonly="true"  
       name="startdate" 
       type="date" 
       data-role="datebox" 
       id="startdate" 
       data-options='{
           "mode": "calbox", 
           "useDialogForceFalse": true, 
           "noAnimation": true,
           "defaultDate": "1999-03-20" // Add Default Date
        }'/>
```

Comment: Thanks,your solution works perfectly.However ,it does not work with Firefox 3.5, however it works on Android based device -Nexus one. So, it solves my issue.

Comment: Hi I'm unable to get the startDate to work on iOS, firefox, safari or chrome. I'm working with the latest jQuery Mobile and have the following options set in the input html tag, data-options="{'mode': 'calbox', 'defaultDate': '1999-03-20', 'dateFormat': 'YYYY-MM-DD', 'headerFormat': 'YYYY-MM-DD'}" Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks Gary

Comment: The developer is always improving the plugin, I would check out: https://github.com/jtsage/jquery-mobile-datebox and http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/ or drop him an email as well.

Comment: Thanks Phil, I have sent him a tweet I will report back if I get a response.